# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to browse a website for testing through python-selenium. But firefox keeps saying Insecure connection.I added permanent exception for that page, the exception works fine when I manually visit that webpage but not through selenium. I created a custom profile based on different suggestions I found in Internet. I added the following lines in my code but its still not working through selenium. I'm using ubuntu14.04

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory="/home/ubuntu/validation/selenium")
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

#I also tried by adding these lines to the above lines, but none of the things are working for me.

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['handleAlerts'] = True
firefox_capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
firefox_capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
```